# The created date of file is lost after pushing my files to GitHub

Tags: github

The "created" date is lost after I push my files to git. When I clone my repository the "created" date is the current date. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

When you clone a repository, Git does not check files out using the original time specified in your commits.  Instead, it creates the files as normal, using the current time.

This is in fact normal, and it also has the nice benefit of working properly with Make, which uses the file time to determine whether a file is in need of being rebuilt.  Since Git always uses the current time, and files Git has checked out will be considered as changed, and Make will build any products that depend on them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's normal.

As far as file metadata (created, last modified, executable or not, etc.) goes git only saves if the file is executable or not. The other values like when it was created are completely managed by your filesystem independent from `git`.

When you clone the repository the files are created now on your filesystem -  so the created metadata of the file is the current date.